# Should I have second child

Tags: parents

me and my husband always wanted to have 2 children as a perfect family, I have one 5-year-old daughter, I always have to be active to keep her busy and play with her like a kid, when she was 3 years old we decide to have a second child and I gave birth to such a lovely second daughter but just after one month she had a liver problem and we lost our second child, now again I come up with that question should we have a second child or not because when I see my daughter I always feel she is gonna be alone she need some one to play with, what gonna happen when we both died, she is gonna be alone forever, she is gonna be lonely, no body will ask about her, no body will take care of her or think about her, trust me this feeling is not good especially as a mom, but when thinking of having second child remind me feeling of sick kids NICU and no body giving the reason of having the liver failure on the second child, now I really want second for my daughter for me but I am afraid of having the second baby. what if my second one is not gonna be healthy and if I born unhealthy baby than I might lose my first one because one unhealthy baby take your all attention, have to give 24 hours  just take care of your baby, I am really afraid of my life as I don't have a family for support or not even my husband family that dreaming of having a good life for my daughter I don't want to mess up and I can't see her alone, I request you all of you please give me any solution, I can't listen to every day mummy where are you gonna take me today with whom I am gonna play today, whenever I take her to her friend she doesn't want to come because she gets bored, she said home is boring....

Comment: This question has quite a few problems.  First, it currently has no punctuation at all and is just one long run on sentence, making it prohibitively hard to read.  Second, no one will be able to tell you what you should do here.  Any answer will just be someone's opinion on what they think would be best.  And those kind of questions don't work on this site.  Sorry.

Comment: When I was a child, I wanted a baby brother or sister too. I didn't think much about the practicalities and pros and cons of it, all I wanted was a "plaything". I'm glad my parents didn't listen to my dumb 6 year old self. As an adult, I realised having only 1 child was the best thing for them, and me too. May not be the best for your family, but my point is, don't let a 5 year old's incessant asking make this life changing decision for you. Also, don't let strangers on the internet make this decision for you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if I understand your question correctly you seem to have some issues with your current daughter being very needy. I understand that. What we do is make very clear what times I'm willing to play with them and at what times I can't. For example, before cooking dinner I'll talk to my son what he is going to do. I'll say. "I'm going to cook dinner. How about you go play with your legos and I'll look at it when I'm finished cooking dinner".

Secondly, you seem to be afraid that your third child might not be healthy. If you worry about that talk to your doctor. I don't know what liver condition your second daughter had. We can't tell if you have any risk of that happening with your third child.

Finally, Don't depend on another child for your family to be perfect. You can already make it perfect right now. Any family will have ups and downs. Sometimes your kids might play with each other but being 5 years apart also means often they don't. (5 years apart is a big deal for anyone under 18). Eventually, your daughter will grow up and raise her own family, have her own kids. Having siblings is great but you won't doom her to loneliness if she doesn't have siblings.